# jQuery: assigning a DIV the class, "active", depending on window.location.hash

Tags: jquery, html

First post here so bear with me.

I'm writing a jQuery function that assigns a background image (`bgImage`) to a div (`#title`) and also giving another div the active class then fading in that active div depending on what `window.location.hash` returns. The `bgImage` for `#title` works just fine but when I assign the div name to the variable that is later given the active class, all of the divs are assigned the active class as opposed just the one. As a result, they all fade in when I call the `panelIn` function. Here's my code:

```
function logoChange() {
switch (window.location.hash) {
    case '#art':
        var bgImage = 'url(assets/logo__ART.svg)';
        var activeP = '#art';
        break;

    case '#about':
        var bgImage = 'url(assets/logo__ABOUT.svg)';
        var activeP = '#about';
        break;

    case '#contact':
        var bgImage = 'url(assets/logo__CONTACT.svg)';
        var activeP = '#contact';
        break;

    default:
        var bgImage = 'url(assets/logo__DESIGN.svg)';
        var activeP = '#design';
        break;
       };
console.log(window.location.hash);
$('#title').css('background-image', bgImage);
$(activeP).addClass('active');
};

function panelOut() {
    if (!$('.panel').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.panel').transition({opacity: 0});
    }
}

function panelIn() {
    if ($('.panel').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.panel').transition({opacity: 1});
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance. I'm very new to jQuery and am learning along the way.

UPDATE: The following is the relevant HTML code.

```
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title"></div>
            <ul id="navigation" class="roboto">
                <li><a id="link-design" href="#design" data-hover="design">design</a></li>
                <li><a id="link-art" href="#art" data-hover="art">art</a></li>
                <li><a id="link-About" href="#about" data-hover="about">about</a></li>
                <li><a id="link-contact" href="#contact" data-hover="contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <!-- Design -->
        <div id="design" class="panel">
            <p>Some Text.</p>
        </div>

    <!-- Art -->
        <div id="art" class="panel">
            <p>Some Text 2.</p>
        </div>

    <!-- About -->
        <div id="about" class="panel">
            <p>Some Text 3.</p>
        </div>

    <!-- Contact -->
        <div id="contact" class="panel">
            <p>Some text 4.</p>
        </div>
</body>
```

UPDATE 2:

This is the new jQuery code that now works perfectly.

```
function pageChange() {
    $('.panel.active').removeClass('active');
    switch (window.location.hash) {
        case '#art':
            var bgImage = 'url(assets/logo__ART.svg)';
            var activeP = '#art';
            break;

        case '#about':
            var bgImage = 'url(assets/logo__ABOUT.svg)';
            var activeP = '#about';
            break;

        case '#contact':
            var bgImage = 'url(assets/logo__CONTACT.svg)';
            var activeP = '#contact';
            break;

        default:
            var bgImage = 'url(assets/logo__DESIGN.svg)';
            var activeP = '#design';
            break;
       };
console.log(window.location.hash, activeP);
$('#title').css('background-image', bgImage);
$(activeP).addClass('active');
};

function panelOut() {
    $('.panel.active').transition({opacity: 0});
}

function panelIn() {
    $('.panel.active').transition({opacity: 1});
}
```

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: if you console.log $(activeP) what does it give you?

Comment: and depending on how you use your code, it might be that you have to remove 'active' from the other divs, before you do addClass('active')

Comment: @Quince Post has been updated to show my HTML.

Comment: @acriel At the home page, it gives me #design, which makes sense. I'll try removing 'active' from all divs first before the function runs and see how that works out.

Comment: what you see when you run `$(activeP)` in console? are you executing panelOut() correctly?

Comment: @Khaleel When I start the page, I am not expecting 'panelOut()' to run. Only '#design' should fade in. In this case, though, all four divs (#art, #about, #contact, #design) are fading in. UPDATE: Console is returning exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function should be

```
function panelIn() {
    $('.panel.active').transition({opacity: 1});
}
```

And the same for panelOut

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you. Could you look at my `panelOut` function? It isn't working as well. I'm not sure how to call the div without the `active` class.

Comment: @NicoJan for panelOut try `$('.panel.active').transition({opacity: 0});` but I'm not sure if this is the behavior you need for this one

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea why I didn't see that. I have one last problem, though. When `window.location.hash` changes and the new active div loads up, so does the previous one because the class wasn't removed. I'm not sure where to put `$('.panel.active').removeClass('active');` in `$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){panelOut(); setTimeout(panelIn, 400);}`.

UPDATE: Never mind. I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @NicoJan I think you can add `$('.panel.active').removeClass('active');` just before `$(activeP).addClass('active');` in `function logoChange()`

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thanks so much for your help.